# Angular: ag-grid is resetting after I apply grid options

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Thanks to someone here, I am setting a sort model on my agGrid, and I told it to auto-size all columns. As I'm stepping through the debugger, I can see the changes taking effect. But then, *something else* executes, and the grid is reset to what I guess is it's default state. What could that be?

Here's the HTML definition:

```
<div>
    <br>
    <div class="domain-form-input"></div>
    <h1>Refresh Job Log</h1>
    <br>
    <data-table *ngIf="portfolioData"
                [setData]="portfolioData"
                [columnDefinition]="columnsDefinition"
                [selectable]="selectable"
                [highlight]="highlight"
                (onRowDoubleClick)="onRowDoubleClick($event)"
                [showSearchBar]="false"
                (onCellClick) = "onCellClick($event)"
                (onDataGridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    >
    </data-table>
</div>
```

And a snippet of the .ts:

```
public onGridReady(params): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    const sortModel = [
        {colId: 'refreshJobStart', sort: 'desc'}
    ];
    this.gridApi.setSortModel(sortModel);
    this.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = this.selectable ? this.getDefaultColumnsDefinition() : null;
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.getAllRefreshJobs();
}
```

I don't know a whole lot about UI development in general, but I understand events, and I can't see what event is causing my grid to reset. In the debugger, the event queue is "purged", and that's when my changes are undone. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share stackblitz for the same

Comment: I'm sorry, what's a stackblitz? The stacktrace?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Well, here it is, but so many imports aren't there that I don't know how to make it work. https://angular-1rqp1n.stackblitz.io

Comment: I'm starting to see the problem. The `data-table` in the html is a common component that we use throughout the app. It has its own `gridReady` event. How do I suppress that event from firing?

Comment: I tried `params.stopPropagation`, but that gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything I could find to stop the event propogation (none of which worked), I finally came up with this kluge. I set a property on the grid `modifyColumnState`, and in the component ts of the `data-grid`, I tell it not to do its thing if that property is set to false. Hope that clear to anyone else having trouble.

```
   <data-table *ngIf="portfolioData"
                [setData]="portfolioData"
                [columnDefinition]="columnsDefinition"
                [selectable]="selectable"
                [highlight]="highlight"
                (onRowDoubleClick)="onRowDoubleClick($event)"
                [showSearchBar]="false"
                (onCellClick) = "onCellClick($event)"
                (onDataGridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                [modifyColumnState] = "false"
    >
    </data-table>
```